# geth node sync err="action from bad peer ignored"

Tags: linux, sync

```
Linux version 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org)  
 (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) )  

[root@izbp19z5o9dc8zqyw88smwz ~]# geth version
INFO [07-28|15:00:32.172] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096  
WARN [07-28|15:00:32.172] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=4096 updated=2607  
Geth  
Version: 1.9.2-unstable  
Git Commit: f34a3a68054eaad15d76c871eeabfa854df47dae  
Git Commit Date: 20190725  
Architecture: amd64  
Protocol Versions: [63]  
Network Id: 1  
Go Version: go1.11.5  
Operating System: linux  
GOPATH=  
GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang  

I run the following command on my shell:  
### geth --syncmode fast --testnet --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8545 console 2>sync_fast_test.log   

and just get the err message:  
Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:08:54.210] Dropping unsynced node during fast sync  id=ddc5d61efa484be9 conn=dyndial addr=62.113.241.17:30303  type=Geth/v1.7.2-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.8
WARN [07-28|15:09:15.536] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:09:20.509] Served eth_sendRawTransaction            reqid=1 t=445.064µs err="insufficient funds for gas * price + value"
WARN [07-28|15:09:45.305] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:10:25.846] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:11:05.679] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:11:45.662] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:12:24.444] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:12:55.486] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:14:14.282] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:14:44.687] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:15:24.755] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [07-28|15:16:05.439] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=c7e7675577416d6b err="action from bad peer ignored"  
WARN [07-28|15:16:38.723] Served eth_sendRawTransaction            reqid=1 t=374.085µs err="insufficient funds for gas * price + value"
```

I searched on Google about this issue but there isnn't a complete solution, anyone have an idea?

Comment: You are probably aware of this but this apparantly seems to be an ongoing issue throughout many recent versions of geth.

Comment: Yes！So it has not a solution right? I want to know what other effects besides the sync-issue，can I trust this network to send my transaction？

Comment: There is no solution I am aware of, no, and it seems many people who are affected by this haven't figured out a workaround either. The basic recommendation is to upgrade (or perhaps use a stable version e.g. v1.9.1?). Unfortunately, I don't think I couldn't offer much relevant advice beyond that (i.e. regarding network trust, etc.) =/

Comment: Your welcome. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my geth client. Also i had the same peer in the error message "c7e7675577416d6b".
What fixed it for me was to add the following when starting geth:

```
--bootnodes "enode://6332792c4a00e3e4ee0926ed89e0d27ef985424d97b6a45bf0f23e51f0dcb5e66b875777506458aea7af6f9e4ffb69f43f3778ee73c81ed9d34c51c4b16b0b0f@52.232.243.152:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303"
```